# Как посчитать число правильных ответов в тесте?

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется тест с вопросами. Известны правильные ответы. После прохождения теста надо сравнить нажатые пользователем варианты с правильными ответами. В случае совпадения данного ответа с подлинным, засчитывать очко за ответ.
В итоге, вывести количество правильных ответов.

Где же закралась ошибка? (не выводит общее количество баллов и радио-кнопки не фиксируются на нужном месте)

```js
function check_answers()

 {

/* id правильных ответов */

  right_answer_1 = 2;
  right_answer_2 = 3;
  right_answer_3 = 1;

 

/* Получение id ответа с формы */

  student_answer1 = document.getElementById('q1').value;
  student_answer2 = document.getElementById('q2').value;
  student_answer3 = document.getElementById('q3').value;


  score = 0;

  if (student_answer1 == right_answer_2) { score = score + 1; }
  if (student_answer2 == right_answer_3) { score = score + 1; }
  if (student_answer3 == right_answer_1) { score = score + 1; }

  
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Тест пройден! Правильных ответов "+score+" из 3.";
 }
```

```html
<div>

<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="1"> Бизнес аккаунт ведут бизнесмены, а личный все остальные люди <br/>

<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q2" value="2"> Бизнес аккаунт обладает более расширенной аналитикой и возможностями продвижения  <br/>

<input type="radio" name="q1" id="q3" value="3"> Личный аккаунт проще продвигать <br/>

</div>

<p> Какое утверждение из нижеперечисленных является правильным? </p>

<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q4" value="4"> Чтобы аккаунт был успешным, необходимо как можно больше публикаций  <br/>

<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q5" value="5"> Имея интернет-магазин плинтусов вам не следует вести социальные сети  <br/>

<input type="radio" name="q2" id="q6" value="6"> С помощью контент плана, вы сможете разделить темы на составные части и не переборщить с публикациями  <br/>



<p> Стоит ли отдавать ведение социальных сетей опытным SMM-щикам? </p>

<input type="radio" name="q3" id="7" value="7"> Нет, это может сделать любой маркетолог  <br/>

<input type="radio" name="q3" id="8" value="8"> Нет, это может сделать любой маркетолог <br/>

<input type="radio" name="q3" id="9" value="9"> Да, ведь специалисты смогут определить вашу ЦА и вести социальные сети правильно <br/>




<button onClick="check_answers();">Узнать Результат</button>
<div id="score"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Где же закралась ошибка?

*Кхм, кхм. "Ошибка" - в единственном числе? Выбирайте:*

---

1 - Не используйте дефис в названиях функций:

```
function check-answers()
{
  ...
```

2 - Задавайте одинаковые значения атрибута `name` только радио-кнопкам с ответами на один и тот же вопрос.

3 - Используйте переменную `result` или переменную `score`, но не обе переменные вперемежку.

4 - Ни у одной из радио-кнопок не задан атрибут `value`. Код, однако, его использует.

5 - У элемента `input` не должно быть отдельного закрывающего тэга `</input>`.

---

*Все, хватит на сегодня.*

```js
function check_answers() {
  var score = 0;
  var questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question");
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    var answer = questions[i].querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked");
    if (answer)
      score += +answer.value;
  }

  document.getElementById('score').textContent = 
    "Тест пройден! Правильных ответов " + score + " из " + questions.length + ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"> Бизнес аккаунт ведут бизнесмены, а личный все остальные люди</label><br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"> Бизнес аккаунт обладает более расширенной аналитикой и возможностями продвижения</label><br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="0"> Личный аккаунт проще продвигать</label><br/>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <p> Какое утверждение из нижеперечисленных является правильным? </p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0"> Чтобы аккаунт был успешным, необходимо как можно больше публикаций</label><br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="0"> Имея интернет-магазин плинтусов вам не следует вести социальные сети</label><br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1"> С помощью контент плана, вы сможете разделить темы на составные части и не переборщить с публикациями</label><br/>
</div>

<div class="question">
  <p> Стоит ли отдавать ведение социальных сетей опытным SMM-щикам? </p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1"> Нет, это может сделать любой маркетолог</label><br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0"> Нет, это может сделать любой маркетолог</label><br/>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q3" value="0"> Да, ведь специалисты смогут определить вашу ЦА и вести социальные сети правильно</label><br/>
</div>

<br/>
<button onClick="check_answers();">Узнать Результат</button>
<div id="score"></div>
```

Comment: я поправил код, согласно вашим комментариям. радио-кнопки включаются все сразу, счетчик на нуле в итоге.

Comment: @DmitryNikitin Нет, не поправили. Попробуйте прочитать мой ответ еще раз.

Comment: радио-кнопки поправил, переключаются. использую только score, однако, счетчик по-прежнему 0.

Comment: как "считать" ответ студента с формы выбора, что поместить в скобках этой конструкции student_answer = document.getElementById("") , вот вопрос

Comment: @DmitryNikitin нет, это не вопрос. Я показал Вам, как сделать правильно. Вам что-то непонятно в коде?